# Browsing Onedrive in a WP8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have managed to connect to LiveConnect, but I am not finding a way to display the contents of OneDrive inside the application.
I have found this [browse task](http://blog.ariankulp.com/2013/11/skydrive-browse-task-for-windows-phone-8.html), but the code supplied does not get it working. Is there a version of FilePicker for C#, or equivalent?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [OneDrive Developer Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/dn632140), there are some options in order to list the files within your storage.

Reference: [Get list of files from SkyDrive folder (Windows Phone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185892/)

Try using this sample from [github](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows) too.

Comment: When I wanted to do something similar in in my universal app, I found this article really useful: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2014/03/26/Using-OneDrive-files-from-a-Windows-8-Store-app.aspx